# How do I rotate a plot clockwise with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to visualize the different backgrunds of our students, the bars represent different high school programs. I write:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov))) + geom_bar()
```

And I get:

[image]

As you can see the names get very cluttered, so I write:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov))) + geom_bar()+coord_flip()
```

And get:

[image]

This "does" look much better, but for optimal effect I would like to show the frequencies in descending order from the top, like my first plot but rotated clockwise.

Is there any way I can make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(test$fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov))))`.

Where `test` is your data frame and `fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov)` is your discrete variable.

Please let me know if it worked :)

Edit: To be more clear add it to `ggplot(test, aes(x=fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov))) + geom_bar()+coord_flip()` so that you get `ggplot(test, aes(x=fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov))) + geom_bar()+coord_flip() + scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(test$fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov))))`

Comment: I write ggplot(test, aes(x=rev(fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov)))) + geom_bar()+coord_flip()+scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(test$fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov)))) and the program tells me "Error in levels(test$fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov)) : 
  attempt to apply non-function"

Comment: If this returns an error, you could try `scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(fct_infreq(test$gymnasiegrov))))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ggplot(test, aes(x=reoder(fct_infreq(gymnasiegrov)),Count)) + geom_bar()+coord_flip()`

Comment: I get "Error in tapply(X = X, INDEX = x, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  argument "X" is missing, with no default"?

Comment: Should I perhaps exchange Category for something else?